# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended when inserting multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I make a script that generates insert statements from SQL data. When I insert just one line of the insert it works but when I try to insert more than one row I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended` here is the insert statement:

This works by itself:

```
INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, SHOP_ID, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, SORT_ORDER, STATUS, VALID_FROM, VALID_TILL, CREATED_AT, MODIFIED_AT, CUSTOM_GRID_LAYOUT_CSS, IMAGE_URL, KEY, SHOW_PRODUCTS_FILTER, MOBILE_APP_IMAGE_URL, LAYOUT_ID, SHOW_OWN_BRAND, VALIDATION_STATUS, CAMPAIGN_USAGE_ID, STORE_END_DATE, PAGING_ALLOWED, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_URL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_URL, CAROUSEL_HTML_OVERLAY, MOBILE_APP_TEASER_URL, CAROUSEL_CLAIM_URL, CAROUSEL_HERO_URL, CAROUSEL_BOX_COLOR, AVOID_CAMPAIGN_NAV_TEASER, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_NEW_TAB, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_NEW_TAB, SALE_QUALIFICATION_ID, SALE_TARGET_CAMPAIGN) VALUES (CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'C', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 1, null, '5_COL', 0, null, 4, to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 0, null, null, 'Artikel ab Mo., 02.12.', 'https://www.lidl.de', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0);
```

Now I add another row to it separating it by a `,` character and ending the whole statement with a `;` character.

```
INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, SHOP_ID, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, SORT_ORDER, STATUS, VALID_FROM, VALID_TILL, CREATED_AT, MODIFIED_AT, CUSTOM_GRID_LAYOUT_CSS, IMAGE_URL, KEY, SHOW_PRODUCTS_FILTER, MOBILE_APP_IMAGE_URL, LAYOUT_ID, SHOW_OWN_BRAND, VALIDATION_STATUS, CAMPAIGN_USAGE_ID, STORE_END_DATE, PAGING_ALLOWED, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_URL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_URL, CAROUSEL_HTML_OVERLAY, MOBILE_APP_TEASER_URL, CAROUSEL_CLAIM_URL, CAROUSEL_HERO_URL, CAROUSEL_BOX_COLOR, AVOID_CAMPAIGN_NAV_TEASER, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_NEW_TAB, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_NEW_TAB, SALE_QUALIFICATION_ID, SALE_TARGET_CAMPAIGN) VALUES 
(CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'C', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 1, null, '5_COL', 0, null, 4, to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 0, null, null, 'Artikel ab Mo., 02.12.', 'https://www.lidl.de', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0),
(CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'P', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 0, null, '4_COL_LEFT_NAV', 1, null, null, null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0);
```

The above one will give me the error. Correct me if I am wrong but inserting multiple rows is allowed like this, correct?

Comment: No, inserting multiple rows like this is not allowed in Oracle.  Simply use two `insert` statements.

Comment: Never saw multiple row inserts in Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

Use insert all.
Below is the example.

```
INSERT ALL  
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (20, 'Google')  
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (21, 'Microsoft')  
  INTO suppliers (supplier_id, supplier_name) VALUES (22, 'Apple')
```

Comment: Yes, this should work. I've added a "SELECT * FROM dual;" at the end of my examples in the past, only because I was getting a syntax error as I think this syntax expects a SELECT. I've written about it before: https://www.databasestar.com/oracle-insert-into/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the syntax diagram in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/appdev.101/b10807/13_elems025.htm), you'll see that there is no reverse arrow after the closing paren for `values`.

Two solutions.  Two `insert`s:

```
INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, SHOP_ID, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, SORT_ORDER, STATUS, VALID_FROM, VALID_TILL, CREATED_AT, MODIFIED_AT, CUSTOM_GRID_LAYOUT_CSS, IMAGE_URL, KEY, SHOW_PRODUCTS_FILTER, MOBILE_APP_IMAGE_URL, LAYOUT_ID, SHOW_OWN_BRAND, VALIDATION_STATUS, CAMPAIGN_USAGE_ID, STORE_END_DATE, PAGING_ALLOWED, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_URL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_URL, CAROUSEL_HTML_OVERLAY, MOBILE_APP_TEASER_URL, CAROUSEL_CLAIM_URL, CAROUSEL_HERO_URL, CAROUSEL_BOX_COLOR, AVOID_CAMPAIGN_NAV_TEASER, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_NEW_TAB, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_NEW_TAB, SALE_QUALIFICATION_ID, SALE_TARGET_CAMPAIGN)
    VALUES (CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'C', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 1, null, '5_COL', 0, null, 4, to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 0, null, null, 'Artikel ab Mo., 02.12.', 'https://www.lidl.de', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0);

INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, SHOP_ID, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, SORT_ORDER, STATUS, VALID_FROM, VALID_TILL, CREATED_AT, MODIFIED_AT, CUSTOM_GRID_LAYOUT_CSS, IMAGE_URL, KEY, SHOW_PRODUCTS_FILTER, MOBILE_APP_IMAGE_URL, LAYOUT_ID, SHOW_OWN_BRAND, VALIDATION_STATUS, CAMPAIGN_USAGE_ID, STORE_END_DATE, PAGING_ALLOWED, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_URL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_URL, CAROUSEL_HTML_OVERLAY, MOBILE_APP_TEASER_URL, CAROUSEL_CLAIM_URL, CAROUSEL_HERO_URL, CAROUSEL_BOX_COLOR, AVOID_CAMPAIGN_NAV_TEASER, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_NEW_TAB, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_NEW_TAB, SALE_QUALIFICATION_ID, SALE_TARGET_CAMPAIGN)
    VALUES (CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'P', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 0, null, '4_COL_LEFT_NAV', 1, null, null, null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0);
```

Or, use `SELECT`/`UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT INTO CAMPAIGN (CAMPAIGN_ID, SHOP_ID, CAMPAIGN_TYPE, SORT_ORDER, STATUS, VALID_FROM, VALID_TILL, CREATED_AT, MODIFIED_AT, CUSTOM_GRID_LAYOUT_CSS, IMAGE_URL, KEY, SHOW_PRODUCTS_FILTER, MOBILE_APP_IMAGE_URL, LAYOUT_ID, SHOW_OWN_BRAND, VALIDATION_STATUS, CAMPAIGN_USAGE_ID, STORE_END_DATE, PAGING_ALLOWED, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_TEXT_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON_BG_COLOR, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_URL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_LABEL, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_URL, CAROUSEL_HTML_OVERLAY, MOBILE_APP_TEASER_URL, CAROUSEL_CLAIM_URL, CAROUSEL_HERO_URL, CAROUSEL_BOX_COLOR, AVOID_CAMPAIGN_NAV_TEASER, CAROUSEL_BUTTON1_NEW_TAB, CAROUSEL_BUTTON2_NEW_TAB, SALE_QUALIFICATION_ID, SALE_TARGET_CAMPAIGN)
    SELECT CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'C', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 1, null, '5_COL', 0, null, 4, to_date('2116-11-23', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), 0, null, null, 'Artikel ab Mo., 02.12.', 'https://www.lidl.de', null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0
    FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAMPAIGN_SEQ.nextval, 1, 'P', 0, 'A', to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2116-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2016-11-09', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), to_date('2018-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), null, null, null, 0, null, '4_COL_LEFT_NAV', 1, null, null, null, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, 0, 0, 0, null, 0
    FROM dual;
```